# CSS transformations crashing Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu (12.04.1 LTS) using VirtualBox (4.1.14) on a Windows 7 host machine. It seems that, using Chrome (21.0.1180.89), CSS transformations are causing the browser to lock up in a strange fashion.

This can be tested using this page: http://benmurden.com/css3test/css3test.html

In short, it looks like the "content area" of the browser, that is, anything apart from the URL bar, tab list etc. stops rendering during or after a CSS transformation and becomes "stuck" on top of every other open process. I can still close the offending tab or the browser itself since that area of the browser is fully responsive. I can even switch to another process and it will be partially visible under the "stuck" content area on top of it.

I meant to take a screen cap to demonstrate this particular effect but after locking up Chrome in this way and switching to a text editor behind it, only the text editor was fully visible on the screen cap and the locked-up Chrome was nowhere to be seen. This leads me to believe this might be a problem with VirtualBox rather than Chrome itself. Then again, there is someone sitting next to me with a nearly identical setup: Same type of machine running Chrome on Ubuntu using VirtualBox with identical versions of those three and he does not experience this issue.

I am unable to reproduce this on any other browser and host/guest combination I'm currently using. Those are:

- Firefox (15.0.1) on Ubuntu
- Firefox (15.0.1) on Windows 7
- Chrome (21.0.1180.89) on Windows 7

Please let me know if there's any other information I could supply that would be of use.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some more information on your setup: Particularly the version of VirtualBox as well as if you have the guest extensions installed and enabled.

Comment: The VirtualBox version was listed in the original post: 4.1.14. I do have guest additions installed.